# what is the use of $.widget and how it differes from $.extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-widgets

I am new to Jquery widget. i want to know what is the exact use case of `$.widget`. i googled so many links but can't get idea for this ?

i have downloaded jquery widget controls autocomplete textbox,button etc...

Ex:

```
 (function( $, undefined ) {

    // used to prevent race conditions with remote data sources
    var requestIndex = 0;

    $.widget( "ui.autocomplete", {

    .......................................
    });


$.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
    ------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------
});
    });
```

using jquery.widget we can able to extend the object ?  (like $.extend) or it supports inheritance concept in java script.

what is the main use case of $.widget ? without this syntax we can't able to create custom 
plugin in jquery.

why we need that ?

because am going to create custom control so i have some doubts in $.widget ? why we need widget concept  ? and what is the use?

whether it is used only  for declaring the namespace  and classes so we can access/ extend the object in some where like below.

```
$.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
    ------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------
});
```

can anyone give some idea about $.widget how it differs from $.extend

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: [.widget](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/) is a jQueryUI object that allows you to make in place jQueryUI style plugins while [.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is a jQuery method for extending a jQuery object.

Comment: thanks.if am going to create custom control(i.e pure clientside rendering control) like jquery ui autocomplete textbox means  need to use $.widget ?

Comment: whether $.widget is similar to jquery plugin $.fn.pluginname=function(){}

Comment: you don't HAVE to use $.widget, it's there for convenience. It creates a plugin similar to $.fn.pluginname, however it provides an easy framework to automatically handle a lot of the tasks associated with building a plugin such as option,method,setup, and teardown management.